# I want to have the user input and print the average amount of letters used, and the longest name

Tags: java, arrays, class, if-statement, printing

So this is my code, and i want to print out a new line saying what the average number of letters used. And i also want to print the longest name written in.. but i cant make it work.. Any suggestions??

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Write some names. When you are finished write <Avslutt>! :)");
        ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();


        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String input = scanner.nextLine();
            if ("avslutt".equalsIgnoreCase(input)) {
                Collections.sort(names);
                System.out.println("Here is the result (Alphabetical): " + names);
                break;
            } else {
                names.add(input);
            }

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Also, if it is possible, to print the array in a string, without having [test, test, test, test]

Comment: Where are you attempting to print the average number of letters and all that? And how is it not working?

Comment: @user a better way is `String.join(", ", names)`.

Comment: @user where i print "here is the result", i want it to also print average letters in the whole array, and the longest name written in by the user.

Comment: First you need to find the average and the longest name. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Show us what you've tried, and where you're having trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop over the input while not empty line, then add to the list and sum the amount to calculate the average.

For sorting the list using Comparater.comparing by string length

```
 public static void main(String[] a) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Write some names. When you are finished write <Avslutt>! :)");
        List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
        int amount = 0;
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String input = scanner.nextLine();
            if ("".equals(input)) {
                break;
            } else {
                names.add(input);
                amount += input.length();
            }

        }

        double avg = amount / names.size();
        Collections.sort(names, Comparator.comparing(n -> n.length()));
        System.out.println("Longest name: " + names.get(names.size() - 1));
        System.out.println("Average letter used:  + avg);
        scanner.close();
    }
```